# Add space before characters while typing in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to achieve a MS-Word-like management for non-breaking spaces before some characters:

While typing, automatically add non-breaking space before `?`, `!`, `:` etc. (or replace normal space with non-breaking), or add space after `«`, etc. (which are rules in French, for e.g.).

I was doing this in PHP before displaying the content, but it should be much better to have it directly in the Wysiwyg.

Cannot find any plugin / ways to achieve that. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tinymce event on `keydown` (just add `setup` to your tinymce config parameters):

```
....
plugins : 'popup1, popup2,...',
setup : function(ed) {
    //register event handler
    ed.onKeyDown.add(function onkeydown(ed, e)
    {
        // example for '!'
        if(e.charCode == 49 && evt.shiftKey)
        {
            ed.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '&nbsp;');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Adapted it to avoid the "Deprecated API call" of onKeyDown. The doc is quite poor: how can I check if there's a normal space before that `!` and remove it to insert the nbsp? —Thanks!

Comment: Last thing: it doesn't really works in Fx because of this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=290565, if someone has an idea to fix this…

Comment: @Joan, "onkeydown" is tinymce3 code (Tinymce3 is still maintained and not deprecated). Easiest thing to replace the space before "!" is to do it before you send it to the server or do it on the server itself. Client-sided a content.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;!') will do.